The smallest number with a given water capacity
This is the outline of this challenge: Every number greater than or equal to two has a prime factorization. A prime factorization can be represented as a bar graph. Every bar graph has a water capacity. Find the least number n with a given water capacity c.
Let \$PF(n) = p_{1}^{e_1} \, p_2^{e_2}\, ...\, p_k^{e_k}\$ be the canonical prime factorization of n. For example \$PF(48300) = 2^2 \cdot 3^1 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 7^1 \cdot 23^1\$.
Let b_i denote a bar of width one and height p_i^e_i. We stack the bars horizontally next to each other to form a bar graph while retaining the order of the prime factorization:
2^2 : ****
  3 : ***
5^2 : *************************
  7 : *******
 23 : ***********************

(This bar graph was drawn vertically to save space; imagine it rotated.)
If you pour water onto the graph (figuratively speaking), a certain number of cells will be filled with water that cannot drain off:
2^2 : ****
  3 : ***w
5^2 : *************************
  7 : *******wwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
 23 : ***********************

The maximum number of filled cells we call the water capacity of the represented number.
In our example, 17 is the water capacity of 48300. This is also the smallest number that has this water capacity. Another example is 243600, which has a water capacity of 31.
Challenge:
Find the least number n with a given water capacity c. Prove the functionality of your function by giving the list of these numbers for c = 1, 2, 3,..., 24. The output list starts with 60 and ends with 4080. The form of the output is optional.
This is code-golf, so each language's shortest code in bytes wins.

OEIS A275339

Would you mind changing that from 'least…' to 'smallest number…'?

JavaScript (ES6), 145 bytes
-21 bytes and faster code thanks to @tsh
c=>{for(d=n=[];d.reduce(t=>t-Math.min(Math.max(...[v,...d]=d),m=m>v?m:v)+v,c);)for(x=1,m=--n;~m;m%++x||d.push(g()))g=_=>m%x?1:x*g(m/=x);return-n}

Try it online!
Method
For each integer \$n\$, we compute the values \$d_k=k^{e_k}\$ where \$1\le k\le n\$ and \$e_k\$ is the highest value such that \$k^{e_k}\$ is a divisor of \$n\$. We go on until we have:
$$n=\prod{d_k}$$
This gives us a list in which each \$1\$ corresponds to either a composite value or a prime number that is not a divisor of \$n\$.[1]
For instance, \$120\$ gives the list \$[1,8,3,1,5]\$:
$$120=1^0\times 2^3\times 3^1\times 4^0 \times 5^1$$
For each value \$d_k\neq 1\$ in this list, we compute the amount of water that can be poured in this column with:
$$\min(max\_b_k,max\_a_k)-d_k$$
Where \$max\_b_k\$ (maximum before) and \$max\_a_k\$ (maximum after) are the maximum values in the list up to and from the current value respectively. (Note that the current value is included in both cases.)
We return the smallest integer \$n\$ for which the sum of these water amounts is the target capacity.

1. In the last revision of the code, composite values are not included at all in the list. But the reasoning remains the same.

You don't need the max(0, ), since max_bk and max_ak already contains dk, thus the second parameter to max is always non-negative.

N is always 1 after inner loop. So you can replace any m in code by N, and thus save two bytes m=.

c=>{for(d=n=[];d.reduce(t=>t-Math.min(Math.max(...[v,...d]=d),m=m>v?m:v)+v,c);)for(x=1,m=--n;~m;m%++x||d.push(g()))g=_=>m%x?1:x*g(m/=x);return-n}

J, 39 bytes
(]+[~:1#.[:(-~>./\<.>./\.)__^/@q:])^:_~

Attempt This Online!
(              )^:_~   Starting with the input, call the inner function 
                       until the output does not change.

            __^/@q:]   prime factorization as a list of prime powers.

  (-~>./\<.>./\.)      water capacity of each column:
         <.             element-wise minimum of ...
     >./\                cumulative maximum and ...
           >./\.         cumulative maximum from the back.
   -~                   subtract the column heights from this.

     1#.               sum to get total water capacity.
  [~:                  is this not equal to the input?
]+                     add to the current value.


2^/@p: for -1.  Nice use of ~: as an indicator for the iteration!

05AB1E, 15 bytes
∞.ΔÒγPLζðδÚ˜ð¢Q

Try it online or verify four test cases. (It's very slow, so it'll time out for \$n=3\$ or \$n\geq6\$..)
Explanation:
∞               # Push an infinite positive list: [1,2,3,...]
 .Δ             # Pop and find the first value that's truthy for:
   Ò            #  Pop and push its prime factors (including duplicates)
    γ           #  Group the same adjacent factors together
     P          #  Take the product of each inner group
      L         #  Map each product to a ranged [1,product]-list
       ζ        #  Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns, using " " as filler-char
                #  for unequal length rows
         δ      #  Map over each inner list:
        ð Ú     #   Trim all leading/trailing " "
           ˜    #  Then flatten this list of lists
            ð¢  #  Count the amount of " " that are left
              Q #  Check whether this equals the (implicit) input-integer
                # (after which the found result is output implicitly as result)


R+numbers, 186 177 bytes
\(x,n=0)repeat{if({a=numbers::primeFactors(n<-n+1);b=unique(a)^table(a);d=(0*b+1)%o%b;sum(pmax(pmin(apply(d*upper.tri(d),1,max),apply(d*lower.tri(d),1,max))-b,0))}==x)return(n)}

Run in it rdrr.io
Test sequence:
f<-\(x,n=0)repeat{if({a=numbers::primeFactors(n<-n+1);b=unique(a)^table(a);d=(0*b+1)%o%b;sum(pmax(pmin(apply(d*upper.tri(d),1,max),apply(d*lower.tri(d),1,max))-b,0))}==x)return(n)}
`names<-`(sapply(1:24,f),1:24)

#>     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12    13    14    15 
#>    60   120   440   168   264   840  2448   528  1904   624  1360  2295   816  1632 20128 
#>    16    17    18    19    20    21    22    23    24 
#>  1824 48300  3105 15392  2208 13024  2400 10656  4080 

Ungolfed:
\ (x,n=0) {
  repeat{
    if (
      {
        # increment n in the arguments of `primeFactors`
        a=numbers::primeFactors(n<-n+1)
        # heights of bars
        b=unique(a)^table(a)
        # repeat b as length(b) rows to make a square matrix
        d=(0*b+1)%o%b
        # calculate amount of water per bar and sum
        sum(pmax(
          # the lesser height of the tallest bars on either side, minus the bar height
          pmin(
            # vector of tallest bars to the left for each position
            apply(d*upper.tri(d),1,max),
            # vector of tallest bars to the right for each position
            apply(d*lower.tri(d),1,max)
          )-b,
          0
        ))
      } == x ) 
    {
      return(n)
    }
  }
}


I'm not sure how to use TIO/ATO with an imported function (here numbers::primeFactors), can anyone help me with that?

You can use https://rdrr.io/snippets/embedding/ to generate link to rdrr.io online repl. Also, this technically is solution in R+numbers.

@pajonk Thank you!

@Eonema Welcome to the site!

@LuisMendo Thanks! :)

Jelly, 18 bytes
ÆF*/€Rz0t€0Fċ0⁼ð1#

A monadic Link that accepts a positive integer and yields a singleton list containing the first number with that capacity
...or a full program that prints the number.
Try it online!
How?
Starting at the given capacity, and then counting up, find the first number with the given capacity (a number can't have a capacity greater than itself).
Find the capacity of a number by building its prime-factor landscape, overfilling it with water (as if walls of the highest peak were on each side), removing any water not held, and counting the remaining water units.
ÆF*/€Rz0t€0Fċ0⁼ð1# - Link: positive integer, Capacity
               ð1# - set k=Capacity and find the smallest k such that:
ÆF                 -   prime factorization of {k}
  */€              -   reduce each {prime, exponent} by exponentiation
     R             -   range (vectorises) -> [[1..p^e] for each [p,e]]
      z0           -   transpose with filler zero (water)
        t€0        -   trim zeros from each end of each
           F       -   flatten
            ċ0     -   count the remaining zeros -> k's capacity
              ⁼    -   equals {Capacity}?


Charcoal, 66 bytes
ＮθＷ¬⁼θω«→≔⟦⟧υ≔ⅈηＦ…²η«≔Ｘκ⌕Ｘ⁰⮌↨ηκ⁰ζ≧÷ζη¿⊖ζ⊞υζ»≔ΣＥυ⁻⌊⟦⌈…υ⊕λ⌈✂υλ⟧κω»Ｉⅈ

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Too slow on TIO for results of four or more digits. Explanation: Port of @Arnauld's JavaScript answer.
Ｎθ

Input n.
Ｗ¬⁼θω«

Repeat until a number with a water capacity of n is found.
→≔⟦⟧υ≔ⅈηＦ…²η«

Start factorising the next number.
≔Ｘκ⌕Ｘ⁰⮌↨ηκ⁰ζ

Try to raise each factor to its multiplicity.
≧÷ζη

Divide by the result.
¿⊖ζ⊞υζ

Save the prime factorisation if it was nontrivial.
»≔ΣＥυ⁻⌊⟦⌈…υ⊕λ⌈✂υλ⟧κω

Calculate the water capacity.
»Ｉⅈ

Output the found number.
72 bytes for a slightly faster version that can produce four-digit results but not five:
ＮθＷ¬⁼θω«→≔⟦⟧υ≔²η≔ⅈζＷ⊖ζ«Ｗ﹪ζη≦⊕η≔Ｘη⌕Ｘ⁰⮌↨ζη⁰ε≧÷εζ⊞υε»≔ΣＥυ⁻⌊⟦⌈…υ⊕λ⌈✂υλ⟧κω»Ｉⅈ

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: As above except:
→≔⟦⟧υ≔²η≔ⅈζＷ⊖ζ«

Start factorising the next number.
Ｗ﹪ζη≦⊕η

Find the next (prime) factor.
≔Ｘη⌕Ｘ⁰⮌↨ζη⁰ε

Raise it to its multiplicity.
≧÷εζ

Divide by the result.
⊞υε

Save the prime factorisation.

C++ (gcc), 273 237 208 207 205 bytes
[](int c,int&n){int w,m,p,q;for(n=2;q=c!=w;){vector<int>v;w=0;p=2;for(m=++n;m>1|q>1;)m%p?++p,q>1?v.push_back(q),q=1:0:(m/=p,q*=p);for(int&i:v)w+=min(*max_element(&v[0],&i+1),*max_element(&i,&*end(v)))-i;}}

Try it online!
Thanks to ceilingcat and emanresu for reduction
Update: changed to lambda function and ternary operator. I had to switch to gcc because there's an unknown bug for c=0 with clang

You can combine multiple expressions into one with ,, which lets you do if(c)a,b instead of if(c){a;b}, so this can be 268 bytes

MATL, 25 bytes
Based on @ovs' J answer.
`@&YF^ttP,wY>]P&vX<-sG+}@

Try it at MATL online!

Python 2, 238 210 192 177 bytes
def T(d):
 a=e=0
 while d+e:
	A=a=a-1;D=[];x=1
	while~A:
		c=1;x+=1
		while A%x<1:A/=x;c*=x
		D+=[c]*(c>1)
	e=sum(h-min(max(D[:b+1]),max(D[b:]))for b,h in enumerate(D))
 print-a

Try it online!

Could you please add also a Python3 version? Thanks!

@SophiaAntipolis Just replace the mixture of tab/space indentations to just spaces; the A/=x to A//=x; and the print a to print(a), then you'll have a Python 3 answer : try it online.

As suggested by tsh on the JavaScript answer, you can remove the max(0,...) to save 7 bytes.

You use a lot of space and time to calculate x=[b for b in range(2,A+1)if A%b<1][0] only to throw everything away again except for the first element. Python 3, 203 bytes Try It Online

177 bytes

Japt, 25 23 bytes
Gets slower the larger the expected output.
@¶Xk ü Ë×õÃÕcÈð änÃxÉ}a

Try it or verify the first 30 values in the sequence
@¶Xk ü Ë×õÃÕcÈð änÃxÉ}a     :Implicit input of integer U
@                           :Function taking an integer X as argument
 ¶                          :  Is U equal to
  Xk                        :    Prime factors of X
     ü                      :    Group (& sort)
       Ë                    :    Map each group
        ×                   :      Reduce by multiplication
         õ                  :      Range [1,×]
          Ã                 :    End map
           Õ                :    Transpose (padding left with null)
            c               :    Flat map by
             È              :    Passing each through the following function
              ð             :      Truthy (not null) indices
                ä           :      Consecutive pairs reduced by
                 n          :        Inverse subtraction
                  Ã         :    End map
                   x        :    Reduce by addition after
                    É       :      Subtracting 1
                     }      :End function
                      a     :Get the first integer that returns true when passed through that function

